# How can I change default directory in screen when I have defshell set to bash?

Tags: bash, unix, gnu-screen, chdir

I know that you can usually use chdir in your screenrc file to change directory before running a screen command. However, this doesn't work for me if I have `defshell -bash` set. Here's a sample file that doesn't work:

```
    defshell -bash 
    defscrollback 100000

    hardstatus on
    hardstatus alwayslastline
    hardstatus string "%w%=%m/%d %c"

    chdir /Users/myuser/work
    screen -t "work"
```

`$ screen -c testrc`

`$ pwd
/Users/myuser`

Commenting out the first line does the trick, but I'd like to run bash shells in my screens. This is on OSX if that's relevant. My screen command is not aliased.

Comment: What happens if you in an unrelated shell run `cd /tmp`, `bash`, `pwd`? Does it print `/tmp` or `/Users/myuser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `defshell` specifies a *login* shell, which makes it go to the home directory.  According to [`screen`'s manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-defshell-20)

> shell command
>
> Set the command to be used to create a new shell.  This  overrides  the value of the environment variable $SHELL.  This is useful if you'd like to run a tty-enhancer which is expecting to execute the program  specified  in  $SHELL. If the command begins with a **'-'** character, the shell will be started as a login-shell.

If you change that to

```
defshell bash
```

it should not do that.

Comment: That worked! The next problem I encountered was that I didn't have my custom prompt because it wasn't sourcing .bash_profile. So I created a .bashrc and added the following line:  
`source /etc/bashrc`
  
Works like a charm now. Thanks!